# Use Python Requests to do post request in postman

Tags: python, post, postman

I need to use Python to send a post request to an API server.

Which I did in Postman is like below.

[image]

this request require these headers:

```
{
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

And I expect code 200 and something like

```
{
    "data": {
        "image": "mypic"
    }
}
```

How can I send this request by Python?

I have done some test like

```
r = requests.Request(method='POST', url='https://api.myapi.site/api/post', headers={
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}, data={
    'identifier': 'test',
    'token': 'db642912e1a431651c8776',
    'image': open('mypic.png', 'rb')
}).prepare()
s = requests.Session()
rsp = s.send(r)
s.close()
```

But it's not the answer, got a 401 return,

And server said I send a request with a "form-urlencoded" header.

So maybe it not send by data parameter,

But I tried to use params, and Server said I send data which too big.

Please help!

Comment: What error(s) do you get when running your code ? What result do you get when requestion with postman ? Please update your question with both.

Comment: @lee-pai-long I update my question. thx!

Comment: You might be missing some cookies, I had a similar problem with XSRF-TOKEN. In my case 

    client = requests.session()
    client.get(url)
    
    csrf_token = client.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'].replace('%3D', '=')
helped

Answer (score 1):

It seems problem with `'image': open('mypic.png', 'rb')`
It is file-object, but you want to send bytes. Try:

```
'image': open('mypic.png', 'rb').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
response = requests.post(SERVER_URL, headers={}, data={}, files={"file": open(file_path, 'rb')}, timeout=200)
```